# phantomjs-2.0.0 does not convert webpage to png/jpg correctly

Tags: phantomjs

I am using phantomjs-2.0.0-windows to convert wepage file to jpg file. For some file it generate image with black color background. I am using following cmd
phantomjs.exe rasterize.js "index.html" output.jpg 1920px.

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js

View of Input File [image]
[image]

output file after cmd execution

after adding
`page.evaluate(function() {
            document.body.bgColor = 'white';
        });`

I get "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating document.body.bgColor="white"')" this error. 
[image]

Comment: Very odd. Can you include the contents of `rasterize.js` in your question?

Comment: you will get on https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js

Comment: Thanks, can you try modifying the `page.open` function as per https://gist.github.com/bjedrocha/1689a6e4f0daec798070? This will explicitly set the background colour to white.

Comment: Thank you. It is working fine except one file. It gives Error while converting ZIP_1428670369173.html into jpg file. 
I get following console log. 
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.body.bgColor="white"')
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():2
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():3
 I have following information 
When I hit "~/bin/demo/ZIP_1428670369173.html" then It's redirect to default.html. 
I have attached screenshot of html source code of both html file